# Solving equation where unknown is on the exponent

Tags: exponentiation

In general is there a systematic of solving equations of the following form:
$$ a  \exp(bx^2+cx)+ d  \exp(x) = e $$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ are constants and $x$ is the unknown.

Comment: You have been around for almost two years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: In answer to your question, no, there is no closed form solution to this equation in general.

Comment: @Paul is there a way to tell if there exists a real valued solution?